# AWS CLI / Boto3 Cloudsearch Validation conflict

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudsearch

Using the latest awscli package, installed via pip on python 3. Have a validation conflict with AWS Cloudsearch:

Command:

> user@desktop-09:~$ aws cloudsearch define-analysis-scheme --domain-name domain-clitest --analysis-scheme '{ "AnalysisSchemeName": "stopwords", "AnalysisSchemeLanguage": "en", "AnalysisOptions": {"Stopwords": "http"}}'

Returns this error:

> An error occurred (InvalidType) when calling the DefineAnalysisScheme operation: Stopwords must be a json array

I then amend the Stopwords to be a single element array:

> user@desktop-09:~$ aws cloudsearch define-analysis-scheme --domain-name domain-clitest --analysis-scheme '{ "AnalysisSchemeName": "stopwords", "AnalysisSchemeLanguage": "en", "AnalysisOptions": {"Stopwords": ["http"]}}'

It fails again, looking for a string:

> Invalid type for parameter AnalysisScheme.AnalysisOptions.Stopwords, value: ['http'], type: class 'list, valid types: class 'str'

Even the [CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearch/define-analysis-scheme.html) seems contradictory:

> Stopwords -> **(string)**
>
> A **JSON array** of terms to ignore during indexing and searching. For example, **["a", "an", "the", "of"]** . The stopwords dictionary must explicitly list each word you want to ignore. Wildcards and regular expressions are not supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so `Stopwords` is a string value representing a JSON array of the terms to ignore during indexing and searching :

```
user@desktop-09:~$ aws cloudsearch define-analysis-scheme --domain-name domain-clitest --analysis-scheme \
'{ "AnalysisSchemeName": "stopwords",\
   "AnalysisSchemeLanguage": "en", \
   "AnalysisOptions": { "Stopwords": "[\"http\"]" }}'
```